# How to change the default date format in Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, datetime, tokens

I've created a rule to send an html email which contains a date, printed using tokens as `[commerce-order:field_delivery_date]`. In email, the date looks like `2016-07-08 00:00:00 to 2016-08-02 00:00:00`. The date may or may not be an interval.

How can I alter the date format in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)?

I know that I can use something like `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:value:custom:j m] - [commerce-order:field-delivery-date:value2:custom:j m Y]` which outputs `08.07 - 02.08.2016`.

But, I don't always have an interval, I can only have the start date, which should be printed as `08.07.2016`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use what you have defined as the format for `short` / `medium` / `long` format in your Drupal date settings, using either of these tokens:

- `[commerce-order:field_delivery_date:value:short]`
- `[commerce-order:field_delivery_date:value:medium]`
- `[commerce-order:field_delivery_date:value:long]`

However, since your date seems to be a data range, you may have to enable the [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module and its "`Entity tokens`" sub-module to access the date values.

Also, be aware that `Entity tokens` replaces underscores  (= "`_`") in the tokens names by dashes (= "`-`"), so in your case "`field_delivery_date`" becomes "`field-delivery-date`". And with that, this is how it should look like:

- `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:value:short]`
- `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:value:medium]`
- `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:value:long]`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The tokens are replaced with empty strings in the email. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work either. I have Entity API with Entity tokens installed. I have tried `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:short]` `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:medium]` `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:long]`. It works only if I access the start date or the end date, like `[commerce-order:field-delivery-date:value:short]`.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to alter the `[commerce-order:field_delivery_date]` and output the interval in this way `08.07 - 02.08.2016`? Please note that the year is displayed only once, in the end date. Thank you :)

Comment: Your token works, but it won't format the date as I described... I want, for example, to show the year only in the end date. Using your syntax, the both start date and end date will be formatted in the same way.